# Dropping rows of data based off of pandas data frame index

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to drop data based off a certain day within a year in my pandas data frame and I am struggling to figure out the right code to do go about with this process. My data consists of half-hourly observations for 6 years (2001-2007). So ideally, I want to drop 48 observations corresponding to one day in my index ('2004-02-29'). The common sense way I tried it was the method below:

```
    len(data)
    122640

    data = data[data.index != '2004-02-29']

    len(data)
    122639
```

The issue is that this method is only dropping one observation within that day specified. I think I am approaching the boolean statement incorrectly, but I am not sure how to fix it. Can anybody assist me in this process please? I will provide a sample of a variable in my data frame below:

```
   2001-01-01 00:28:48         NaN
   2001-01-01 00:57:36         NaN
   2001-01-01 01:26:24         NaN
   2001-01-01 01:55:12         NaN
   2001-01-01 02:24:00         NaN
   2001-01-01 03:07:12         NaN
   ...............................
   2007-12-31 23:31:12         NaN
   2008-01-01 00:00:00         NaN
   Name: SFO3, dtype: float64
```

Note, I have missing data for the first and last month of each year.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
   add access the date component of the index;
   use a `datetime.date` instead of a string.

```
data = data[data.index.date != datetime.date(2004,2,29)]
```

If you want to remove all leap days, you can use something like this:

```
data = data[(data.index.month != 2) & (data.index.day != 29)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your data but please try (assuming your index is `pd.DatetimeIndex`):

```
import datetime
data[data.index.date != datetime.date(2004,2,29)]
```